# Take a photo and add to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an app that has a takePhoto `UIButton` on a `UIViewcontroller` that enables the user to take a photo by using the `imagePickerController`. I then want the photo to be placed in a `UITableView`.

The photo part works and for testing purposes I have the image displayed in a `UIImage` *photoImageView.image*

I have added the `UITableView` delegate and then `UITable` is called *photoTable* and the cell is called photoCell. I have tried to figure out the code below for adding the image to the table without success. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender 
{
[self startCameraControllerFromViewController: self usingDelegate: self];
}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
UIImage *image;
image = (UIImage *)
[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
photoImageView.image=image;
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate
{
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil)) return NO;
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
cameraUI.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;
cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
[controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)photoTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"photoCell";

UITableViewCell* cell = [photoTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImage.jpg"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the image `property`, and `tableview` outlet in `.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIIImage *photoImage;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
```

in .m file in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
    UIImage *image;
    image = (UIImage *)
    [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.photoImage = image;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //call reloadData method to load data with image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.movieTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.imageView.image = self.photoImage; 

       or use array and add image to array in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: and use the image

       cell.imageView.image = [self.photoArray objectAtIndex:0]; 

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The problem I am facing is that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not being called at all ... [self.tableView reloadData] does not seem to do anything.

Comment: have you created the outlet from your storyboard to .h file, check the  uitableview datasource and delegate protocols as well.

Answer (score 2):

In your following method:

```
imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Add this line:

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Return updated number of rows in:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and in *cellForRowAtIndexPath* modify your code like this:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImage.jpg"];
```

**NOTE:** if you want to show more than one image, like every image you capture, then save images in an array. and retrieve them in *cellForRowAtIndexPath* and assign different image to every cell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. See the comment to Suhit above. And I think it has something to do with linking the delegate to the tableview but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: have u linked your tableview from .xib file to file owner (you view controller)?? check that... after that, in you viewDidLoad method,
add these lines:
_tableView.delegate = self;
_tableView.dataSource = self;
and implement all required delegate methods

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImage.jpg"];
    }
```

Try it, I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I should have added that I have set a debug in the - (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)photoTable routine and it does not even reach it. So something is going wrong before this to not even call it.

Comment: cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImage.jpg"]; put this statment out of brackets if you have different set of images

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to save images in document directory after capture photo

like:

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)imagepk
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *image = imagepk; // imageView is my image from camera
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
    // Code for saving image here

}
```

and then acces from document directory and add in array.

Comment: Thank you - this was going to be the next thing I looked at. Very helpful. Incidentally since I have to do this on the iPad (photos not working on the simulator) do you know how can I check the documents directory to see if the photo is saved there?

Comment: NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];